# Why does Data Grip keep connecting to database?

Tags: datagrip

running Data Grip 2018.3 on OSX 10.12.

It seems that most actions require reconnecting to the DB which makes even simple actions to the DB take longer than expected.

Examples:

- Double clicking on a table to view the data, even on a single row table, takes 20 seconds. The fetch takes 50ms as indicated by the UI, but prior to that the processing wheel displays for a few seconds.
- Or executing a DDL like an insert, again it takes a few milliseconds, but again it seems to start processing for a bit and then it works.
- Or doing a refactoring at the bottom it shows connecting to DB for a few seconds, then it executes and it seems to take long to refresh the UI with the new change. Like renaming a column.

Note these actions are being done on either really small tables or empty tables. So it's not a data size delay.

**Update 2019-01-22:**

- SQL Server 2016
- Non SSH/SSL
- SQL Server JDBC drivers
- UI doesn't freeze. The processing circle appears and rotates.
- Queries runs within milliseconds 100ms or less. Just seems like the connection takes long. See point above.
- It seems to reconnect/synchronize on each action.

Comment: We need some information :)

How does it look like? UI hangs? What database do you use? SSH or SSL enabled? Is everything ok with the network? Server ping is OK as well?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Still no ping information :) But anyway, I'll have a workaround for you.

Comment: Also if you send IDE logs (Help - Shoe logs) to datagrip@jetbrains.com it might help us investigate the issue.

Comment: @moscas the bug is still existing for years but no one fixed it yet.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-16275/Bug-Datagrip-keeps-reconnecting-databases-for-queries-in-UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a problem which needs to be investigated, but there is a workaround:

1. Go to the data source properties
2. Click the *Options* tab.
3. Select *Single connection mode*.
4. Click *Apply*.

[image]

Comment: So here is what I have noticed. In NON single connection mode. A new connection is opened for every action. The logs seem to indicate it takes 10 seconds for each connection. In single connection mode, the first connection takes 10 seconds and the subsequent are instant. Nothing printed in the logs for subsequent connections obviously. When closing all the tabs and starting again, a single connections needs to be established again which takes 10 seconds.

Comment: I emailed you guys.

Comment: And it also seems JTDS works fine in multi connection mode.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like it because JTDS is faster. But your solution for MS driver works.

Comment: I don't have that "Single connection mode" option in my DataGrip, could anybody know why?

Comment: What database do you use?